# SQL SUMIFS checking if a date is within a range

Tags: mysql, sql

in SQL I need to get the sum of adults and children per calendar day from a range of start date and end date of bookings.

[image]

So, for example, on 03/09/2021 I would need to add the 2 adults from booking 178458, the 4 adults from booking 178459, the 3 adults from booking 178460 and 1 adult from booking 178462, giving me a total of 10 adults.

[image]

How can I get this? Thank you very much

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Do you have a calendar table handy?

Comment: Create a calendar help table/cte. OUTER JOIN, GROUP BY.

Comment: I don't have calendar table handy @GordonLinoff

Comment: Good morning @jarlh, could you please be more explicit? Thank you

Comment: SELECT ... FROM bookings RIGHT JOIN calendar on calendardate between startdate and enddate ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c97858b3ddeb079cb27a5c0846a8b884

```
create table bookings (booking_id int, stay_date_start date, stay_date_finish date,  number_adults int, number_children int);
insert into bookings values (178458, '2021-09-01', '2021-09-07', 2, 3);
insert into bookings values (178459, '2021-09-03', '2021-09-06', 4, 2);
insert into bookings values (178460, '2021-09-02', '2021-09-10', 3, 1);
insert into bookings values (178461, '2021-09-04', '2021-09-09', 2, 2);
insert into bookings values (178462, '2021-09-01', '2021-09-11', 1, 0);

select * from bookings;

create table cte_dates (day date);
insert into cte_dates values ('2021-09-01');
insert into cte_dates values ('2021-09-02');
insert into cte_dates values ('2021-09-03');
insert into cte_dates values ('2021-09-04');
insert into cte_dates values ('2021-09-05');
insert into cte_dates values ('2021-09-06');
insert into cte_dates values ('2021-09-07');
insert into cte_dates values ('2021-09-08');
insert into cte_dates values ('2021-09-09');
insert into cte_dates values ('2021-09-10');
insert into cte_dates values ('2021-09-11');

select * from cte_dates;

select c.day, sum(number_adults) as 'number_adults', sum(number_children) as 'number_children'
from bookings as b
right join cte_dates as c
on c.day
between b.stay_date_start and b.stay_date_finish
group by c.day;
```